# How to Set options dynamically ui:inputSelect created by CreateComponent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, create-component

I have created ui:inputSelect using CreateComponent method.
I have set onchange event on that inputSelect. 
onchange of an controlling field I have to set **options** for another inputSelect(dependent field)

component:

```
<div>
     <ui:inputSelect aura:id="ActivityType__c" class="undefined TypeSpecification__c ltngInputSelect" value="{!v.sObject.ActivityType__c}" options="{!v.activty}" change="{!c.onchangeHandler}" >
          <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactLevel}" var="level">
              <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!level}" label="{!level}"/>
          </aura:iteration>
     </ui:inputSelect>
     <ui:inputSelect aura:id="TypeSpecification__c" class="undefined undefined ltngInputSelect" value="{!v.sObject.TypeSpecification__c}" options="{!v.typeSpecification}">
         <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactLevel}" var="level">
             <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!level}" label="{!level}"/>
         </aura:iteration>
     </ui:inputSelect>
</div>
```

My ActivityType and TemplateSpecification are dependent picklist.(Controlling field is ActivityType__c and dependent is TemplateSpecification__c) Both the fields are I am creating using **CreateComponent** method.

Controller onchange method:

```
onchangeHandler : function(component, event, helper) {
   var dependentField = component.get('v.dependentField');
   var dependentFieldOptions = component.get('v.dependentFieldOptions');
   var dependentPicklist = component.find(dependentField);
   dependentPicklist.set('v.options', dependentFieldOptions);
}
```

Here I have dependentFieldOptions, dependentFieldName where I have to set new options based on controllingField onchange.

it throws error at line `dependentPicklist.set('v.options', dependentFieldOptions);` **.set('v.options)** function not found.
if I do `dependentPicklist.set('v.value', somevalue);` it works fine but who to set all the options.

Comment: Would be easier for us to help; if you could edit your question and provide some more code by which we can replicate the issue?

Comment: @Raul Edited the question for better clarification. Let me know if you need any thing else...

Comment: Not sure what was the issue but it is working now without any issue.. it must be some typo mistake I guess..